# CSS font size dynamically between interval

Tags: css, font-size

With small screen size (mobile) the font size is fixed to `14px`. On really large screens, the font size is fixed to `18px`. So it can never be lower than `14px` and never higher than `18px`. The media queries take care of that.

Then we have the middle ground where I want the font size to be dynamic between `14px` and `18px`. For that I use `font-size: calc(.5vw + .85em);` which works ok, but not great. I don't know how to calculate it to start from `14px` and end at `18px` between the screen width `40rem` (16 * 40) and `65rem`.

Any ideas?

```css
.wrap {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: calc(.5vw + .85em);
}

p:before {
  content: 'Desktop: ';
  opacity: .5;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 65rem) {
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  p:before {
    content: 'Desktop large: ';
    opacity: .5;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
  p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  p:before {
    content: 'Mobile: ';
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    text
  </p>
</div>
```

**I also added it here:** https://jsfiddle.net/6ybkp7a1/6/

### Example

When I'm on a screen width of `40.1rem` (just above `40rem`), I should have a font-size like `14.1px` (or whatever it may be), just above `14px`.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/ has a pretty good explanation of the math involved.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. It will go gradually from `14px` to `18px`.

**How it works?**

`100vw` is our screen size so it will vary from `40rem` and `65rem` in the needed region. Minus `40rem` we will have a variation between `0rem` and `25rem`. `25rem` is equal to `(16px * 25) = 400px`. Our variation is now from `0` to `400px` and if we divide by `100` and we add `14px` we have a variation between `14px` and `18px`.

```css
.wrap {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: calc(14px + (100vw - 40rem)/100); /*or 14px + 1vw - 0.4rem */
}

p:before {
  content: 'Desktop: ';
  opacity: .5;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 65rem) {
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  p:before {
    content: 'Desktop large: ';
    opacity: .5;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
  p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  p:before {
    content: 'Mobile: ';
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work perfectly! Thanks! I don't completely understand the formula, but as it's based on my original numbers I guess it should work in all cases. =)

Comment: @JensTörnell I added more explanation to the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set another media query for `min-width: 40rem` along with other media queries you have. That should take care of screen size in between those two screen sizes you have added.

Here's the working example([**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pbxva3u2/3/)):

```css
.wrap {
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
  p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  p:before {
    content: 'Mobile: ';
    opacity: .5;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40rem) {
  p {
    font-size: calc(.5vw + .85em);
  }
  p:before {
    content: 'Desktop: ';
    opacity: .5;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 65rem) {
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  p:before {
    content: 'Desktop large: ';
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this will produce the same result as the initial code

Comment: Yes. It's a nice try but it does not really solve the problem. For example, when I'm on a screen width of `40.1rem` I should have a font size that is just above `14px` like `14.1px` or whatever it will be.